# Splitting the string, integer and also the special character ("_")

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split between the string, integer and also special character, I've try some of the way, but does't work for me, so any ideas on it?

source code:

```
    String a = "abc1_xyz1";

        String[] qq = a.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|('_')");

        for(int i=0; i<qq.length; i++){
            System.out.println(qq[i] + " \n");
        }
```

The expectation output from me is:

```
abc
1
_
xyz
1
```

But what I get is:

```
abc
1
_xyz
1
```

Anyone here can give me the guideline?

Comment: Can you tell us, generally, how the string is supposed to look like?

Comment: One more reason why your regex fails, by the way, is the fact that it requires single quotes around the `_`.

Comment: ya, i just realize that, and also need to put at the front to split first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of small problems.
\D will match _ and you don't expect that in your code
Also, splitting on _ will exclude it from the output.

This code would work

```
    String a = "abc1_xyz1";

    for (String s : a.split("" +
        "(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)" +    // space between letter and digit
        "|(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])" +   // space between digit and letter
        "|(?<=_)(?=\\d)" +       // space between _ and digit
        "|(?<=\\d)(?=_)" +       // space between digit and _
        "|(?<=_)(?=[a-z])" +     // space between _ and letter
        "|(?<=[a-z])(?=_)" +     // space between letter and _
        "")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, it is perfectly work for me, really thanks a lot.

Comment: I agree but this is pretty clear and not very error prone. Simplification usually leads to the code being harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

I think `split()` is the wrong way to go here as you don't really have any delimiter and wants to use everything that is split (it gives you empty lines in between the values).

Instead, assuming the expression is regular I would use `Pattern.compile()` and `Matcher.group()`, as such:

```
    String a = "abc1_xyz1";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)(\\d+)(_)(\\D+)(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
    if (m.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i<=m.groupCount();i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i));
        }
    }
```

If any of the groups are optional, you can add a question mark after it (then the group will be empty).

Comment: This would only work for a string formatted exactly as in the question and not for example 1_abc_2xyx. If the string is formatted exactly the same (same groups) each time I would also prefer this solution as it's much more easy to read.

Comment: ya, it can be more better.=)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: Check for `_` before you check for the digit/non-digit boundaries:

```
String[] qq = a.split("(_)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\D` is "a non-digit". `_` is a non-digit, therefore it will be matched.

Try replacing `\D` in your code with `\p{Alpha}` (matching any ASCII letter) or `\p{L}` (matching any Unicode letter).

Comment: Hi, Joachim, thanks for your information, I just check with other character classes, instead of using \p{Alpha}, the \p{Punct} is more suitable and work for me, thanks a lot.